# How to inject a datasource into an xlsx file

Tags: xml, excel, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, odata

How can I inject an OData source as an xml file in the xlsx file?

I am using OAuth as well, I can connect by providing a bearer token in the header through the advanced query editor. I am trying to create the connection through the xml files, but I can't find where the connection happens.

I have found the difference between an empty workbook, and a workbook with the connection, the customXml folder, the connections.xl file in the xl folder, the [Content_Types].xml file, and the workbook.xml.rels file in the _rels folder in the xl folder.

However I cannot find anything about the connection string, or bearer token in any of those files, the item1.xml file in the customXml folder contains utf-8 text, when converted has a a lot of information on the query, but nothing about the feed or token, it also has contains portions that are unreadable such as:
"y  PK   �L�H���O�   �     Config/Package.xml � (�"

So I'm trying to find where the connection information is stored in the xml files, in order to add the OData feed directly in the xml.

Edit: This is for injecting/checking the source programmatically. The main goal is to be able to return a file from a website that has an OData feed as a data source. The reason this has to be done programmatically rather than a prebuilt file is because we have to inject the authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Power Query and create a query to an OData feed.

[image]

Power Query is a [free add-in for Excel 2010 and 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379) and it is built into Excel 2016 as Get and Transfrom in the data ribbon.

Comment: Sorry this isn't what I meant, I can import the feed through excel fine, but because it is protected with OAuth I need to put a bearer token in the header, I can do that through advanced query editor, but I am trying to do it through the xml files instead.